# Creating simple slice of state with recoil

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recoiljs

I have an api request and I like to store the response in Recoil atom.
I am trying to figure out what is the best way of doing so.
The thing is that my selector doesn't have dependency (atom) since my request has no parameters:

```
const connectionsQuery = selector({
  key: "Connections",
  get: async () => {
    const connections = await findConnections();
    return connections;
  },
});
```

When I execute the following, I get on informative error:
[image: error]

This is how I used the selector:

```
function DashboardLayout() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [isMobileNavOpen, setMobileNavOpen] = useState(false);
  console.log(222);
  const connections = useRecoilValue(connectionsQuery);
  console.log(333);
  ...
  ...
```

'222' console logged but '333' was never logged.

What am I missing?

Comment: As for as I can see，there is nothing wrong with recoiljs. The error probably occur whthin `findConnections`, try debugger in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to wrap your component with Suspense. `await`ing a selector means that the component depending on the value of that selector will suspend rendering until there is a value, because Recoil internally will **throw** a promise (which is the whole idea behind suspending in React).

So to make it work wrap your `DashboardLayout` component with a Suspense component:

```
<React.Suspense fallback={<div>loading...</div>}>
  <DashboardLayout/>
</React.Suspense>
```

This is also stated in the [recoil docs](https://recoiljs.org/docs/guides/asynchronous-data-queries#asynchronous-example).
To learn more about concurrent mode and suspense, you should read the official [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-intro.html) to understand the mechanics behind it.

Answer (score -1):

```
const connectionsQuery = selector({
     key: "Connections",
     get: async ({ get }) => {
          const connections = await get(findConnections);
          return connections;
     },
 });
```

i think you missing get props,
findConnections is a atom state for your response request, really ? or a function ?

Comment: `findConnections` is async function that fetches connections